# axios duplicates the url in the interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using Axios for my HTTP request and this is my first time I got this problem.
the first request is passed and everything is good. but in my second request, I have a problem that Axios is duplicate my URL without reason.

the url that axios is trying to fetch at the end looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/http://localhost:3001/http://localhost:3001/user/5e4844f6451e0078e7dd398e
```

this is the fetch action:

```
export const getUserDetailsById = async ({id}) => {
    return await axios.get(`user/${id}`).then(res => res.data);
};
```

and the interceptor:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem(process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN_NAME);
        config.headers.common['authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        config.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        config.url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${config.url}`;

        const url = config.url;
        console.log(url);

        return config;
    },  function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you console.log these values and check them? `process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL` and `config.url`

Comment: http://localhost:3001/user/5e4844f6451e0078e7dd398e
interceptor.js:11 

http://localhost:3001/http://localhost:3001/user/5e4844f6451e0078e7dd398e
interceptor.js:11 

http://localhost:3001/http://localhost:3001/http://localhost:3001/user/5e4844f6451e0078e7dd398e

Comment: So the problem is there, correct your values inside those.

Comment: @SuleymanSah what happened is before the request sent, the interceptor repeating itself and append the URL again and again. this piece of code always worked for me and i don't know what's changed

Comment: Don't change the config.url  value.  Just delete config.url = ".." line , and return this `return ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/${config.url}`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `baseURL` when calling `axios.create`

```
import axios from 'axios';

var api = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${AppConfig.apiUrl}/services`,
});

export default api;
```

then import `api` when ever you want to use axios.

Comment: this working of course, but the strange this is that this piece of code is like a boilerplate that I built for myself and it always worked fine